# BackRequested event crashes the app in Windows 10 Mobile v. 1511

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm making web browser for UWP on all Windows versions. So, I'm noticed that when WebView navigating from YouTube site to YouTube video (when navigation not completed on that time), when I pressed the hardware back button, the app crashes. The strangest things are that this doesn't occur when the app is running from debug or release mode. Also, when the same code I write the same code on Back button of my app, the function works perfectly. Also, the same crash occurring when I'm writing some code on `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested` event no matter what. The same thing is on `HardwareButtons.BackPressed`. The code is:

```
    private void CurrentView_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        if (appView.IsFullScreenMode)
        {
            appView.ExitFullScreenMode();
        }
        else
        {
            Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (!frame.CanGoBack && currentWebView.CanGoBack)
            {
                currentWebView.GoBack(); //the real function
            }
            else
            {
                if (PivotMain.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    CloseOneTab(PivotMain.SelectedWebViewItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**: the app doesn't crash when WebView is set on `WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread`. But somewhy I think that it's risky ‍♂️.

Comment: Does problem only occur in the mobile?

Comment: Yes, this problem occurs only in mobile

Comment: Have  you tested with surface?

Comment: I've tested in tablet mode in versions: 2010, 1607, 1507 on desktop. On mobile I've tested in 1511 version. So my app have both Desktop and Mobile UAs, I'm picked Mobile UA. So in 1607 and 1507 versions of desktop the YT videos aren't loading, and writes that browser can't play video (but strangely in W10M the all videos are playing normally in same UA), however, in desktop's v. 2010 plays too and the crash occurs only in mobile and only when I touching back button when the navigation from page to video doesn't fully completed.

Comment: Yep, it's hard to say, if it can't reproduce in desktop, it means that is more related specific device. you know there is no os update for mobile device currently. So far, set on WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread is  a good workaround.